# Unable to use my DRF serializers manually

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Very strange but whenever I try to use any of my DRF serializers to serialize an object, like  for instance:

```
me = CustomUser.objects.all()[0]
serializer = CustomUserSerializer(me)

serializer.is_valid()
# --> False
print(serializer.errors)
# {"non_field_errors": ["No input provided"]}
```

and this happens with totally different serializers and various objects.

However, if I use a class-based view (that indirectly uses the same serializers and the same objects), I am able to receive a JSON response with the data serialized as expected. Said differently, calling an endpoint linked to this view

```
class CustomUserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer
```

will indeed return a JSON representation of all the `CustomUsers` in the database.

There must be something I did not quite understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Django REST Framework allows you to serialize an object by passing it into a serializer through the `instance` keyword (or the first positional argument). From there, you just need to call `data` on it. This is all covered in the [serializing objects](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-objects) part of the documentation.

```
me = CustomUser.objects.all()[0]
serializer = CustomUserSerializer(me)
serializer.data
```

You only need to call `is_valid` when you are [deserializing data into an object](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#deserializing-objects). The error you are getting ("No input provided") is because you are trying to validate the data to be deserialized, but you are passing no data in.

Comment: Great. I don't know why I was trying to validate something that is valid by definition. Thanks